# Next JS fetch API by url query param

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

Helo, i was develop web app using next js using react query for fetch api and now have a problem, when create local storage from `_app.tsx` base on url param

```
http://localhost:3000?token=123456789
```

and if i access it from index page, this local storage was not found

```
// app.tsx

import '../styles/globals.css';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { Hydrate, QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { isReady, query }: string | any = useRouter();
  const [queryClient] = useState(
    () =>
      new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
          queries: {
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            staleTime: 0,
            retry: false,
          },
        },
      })
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isReady) {
      if (query.token) {
        console.info('token ', query.token);
        localStorage.setItem('token', query.token);
      } else {
        window.console.info('no token');
      }
      console.info('current token ', window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
    }
  }, [isReady]);

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Hydrate>
      <ReactQueryDevtools />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

and below when i try to access token from local storage it was not found

```
  const { data, error, isFetching } = useQuery('event_list', () =>
    getEventList({
      token: window.localStorage.getItem('token') || null,
      query: {
        order_start: 'desc',
      },
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you render your page even if `isReady` is false, the query will likely fire off once before the effect that sets the localStorage item kicks in. Since the token is not a dependency to the query, it won't refetch if the token changes.

What you can do is:

- not render your app if `isReady` is false / you have no token, but that will likely disable SSR altogether.
- put the token in react context, access it in your query and put it into the query key. That will make sure your query re-fetches when the token changes. You can also disable the query while it has no token:

```
const token = useTokenFromContext()
const query = useQuery(
  ['event_list', token],
  () => getEventList(token),
  {
    enabled: !!token
  }
)
```